# Add a <LineBreak /> component within block code

Tags: reactjs

I have this small component that renders attachments' names. I would want to add a line break between each attachment name, I have a `<LineBreak />` component but I'm not sure what's the right syntax to add the component here.

I tried:

```
return file.name + <LineBreak />
```

and:

```
return file.name + (<LineBreak />)
```

But they both didn't work.

```
export default function AttachedFile({ attachments }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to="./" css={text}>
        {Array.from(attachments).map(file => {
          return file.name; // How do I add the <LineBreak /> component here?;
        })}
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `return <>{file.name}<LinkBreak/></>` or `return <div>file.name</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the simplest solution would be to use a fragment:

```
   <NavLink to="./" css={text}>
    {Array.from(attachments).map((file, index) => (
      <React.Fragment key={index}>
        {file.name}<LineBreak />
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </NavLink>
```

Note that you should have a `key` in the iteration anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the first solution using `Fragment ` works, the second one with the `join` doesn't. The output is `attachmentName[object Object]`

Comment: @user3378165 you are right, that wouldnt work in javascript, because `join` returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function AttachedFile({ attachments }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavLink to="./" css={text}>
        {Array.from(attachments).map(({ name }, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            {name}
            <LineBreak />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here the `.map` is returning a `React.Fragment` which contains two elements, first is the name of the file, second is the `<LineBreak>` component.